# Are there any benefits to marriage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So now that I have an Amulet of Mara, apparently I can choose to marry certain NPCs.

But I'm wondering, are there any tangible upsides to marriage that'd make wooing that special someone worth it, gameplay-wise?

Comment: +1 for the title, and I'd say "no". But my answer is a "out of topic" answer ;)

Comment: Migrate to RealLife.SE? ;-)

Comment: "Spouses with benefits"?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can let him/her get profits, cook food and get a 15% skill-learning boost after sleeping together.

> After the Marriage, your partner will ask where do you want to live and you will have the choice of living with them, or if you have a house, live there. If your spouse relocates to a different City from where they originated to live in one of your houses, they may indicate that they wish to become a shopowner to keep occupied while you are adventuring. If this occurs, you can ask them once a day how the shop is going to receive a share of the profits (approximately 100 gold per 24 hours). You will also be able to buy and sell from/to your spouse as would a regular merchant NPC.
>
> Once a day, you can ask a spouse to cook something for you. They will make a Homemade Meal that increases the regeneration of magicka, health, and stamina. If you sleep in the house with your spouse, you will get a temporary bonus called, 'Lover's Comfort' that boosts your rate of skill-learning by 15% for eight hours.
>
> — [Wikia - Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim - Marriage](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage)

---

If any, watch out for the following two bugs:

> - A bug can occur during the wedding ceremony at the Temple of Mara. After Maramal pronounces the player and the player's NPC of choice married, the NPC may start walking toward the temple's exit before Maramal is done speaking and player can move. If the NPC leaves the temple before the player can speak to him/her about where they will live, then the NPC will disappear. They will reappear if they are part of a quest, like Ysolda in "A Night to Remember". However, after you say "I do" if you exit the speech and click on your spouse fast enough before he/she walks out the door, he/she will not disappear. But even if you tell them to move into your house they may or may not actually be there. They will be at their prevous house instead.
> - A bug can occur in which a scripted NPC interrupts the wedding if you choose to wait overnight in the Temple of Mara. For example: the priestess of Azura might make you miss your wedding if you recently complete the Azura's Star quest. What results is that you miss your wedding, but still have the option to make it up to the other person.
>
> — [Wikia - Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim - Marriage](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage)

Comment: I do what I can. ♪

Comment: "her"? You mean "him", right? ;) (More seriously: girls game too, and let's not make women feel ignored if we can help it! "Him/her", "them", or just "your partner" like the quote uses would all be most welcome edits.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: You also have those players that choose a character of the opposite sex. Corrected! :)

Comment: Heh, funny how both bugs basically cause a 'runaway spouse'.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm sure anyone reading this would instantly reallize he could be switched with she. I doubt there are any people that would not make that connection. Don't be a jerk.

Comment: @Patar It still sends women the message that they're an afterthought, especially since it's so easy to fix. I'm glad you don't want to accidentally be a jerk to fellow gamer women. :)