# Should werewolves get married?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

According to the accepted answer to this question on [the benefits of marriage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35957/are-there-any-benefits-to-marriage), if I were to get married I would get

- a piece of food once a day (if I remember to ask for it),
- a bit of cash once a day (if I remember to ask for it), and
- some lovin' to give me a rest bonus (if I can stay awake long enough after a tiring day of adventuring).

Now, I am a Level 30+ werewolf. Which means that

- I rarely eat food I haven't killed myself.
- I have tons of cash, like most players at this stage, so 100 per day is negligible.
- I. Am. A. Werewolf. No resting bonus. Not even Lover's Comfort, according to the [wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sleeping).

Even if I were much lower-level, food doesn't seem very useful in the game and the amount of cash you get is quite small. Does my...*hairy* condition effectively negate the only real advantages to marriage?

Comment: Related: http://www.reddit.com/tb/nadxw

Comment: I think Alea is a werewolf, and she can be married after doing the companions questline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, for you it'd mostly be for role playing purposes. There is one exploit that may or may not be beneficial to you depending on how much you need money. As that 100 septims stack, you can sleep for 24 hours 10 times for example and get a 1000 gold. This was slightly helpful for me when I was trying to buy loads of Master spells at 3000 each.

Apart from that its pretty much useless gaming wise especially if you do not need money.

Comment: That's something to consider. Strange, I thought getting married would mean my wife *taking* my money ;) (for Iron Boots of +2 Fabulous)

Comment: also you can sell things to them, so they can be a convenient merchant and they surprise with gifts. I have only got one so far but I have not been married very long.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer, simply not so.  Usefulness of marriage also goes in to who you marry.  The blacksmith in Riften for example.  If you're trying to get good prices at an smith(on ebony ore without having to mine it for example) this helps.

Comment: that still comes down to money though, right? getting better prices when you have tons of money can't make that much of a difference...

Comment: sort of, also game time.  it's more efficient to unload gear, pick up gold, and accumulate ebony at the same time.  i'm making full daedric sets for all of my followers btw

Answer (score 3):

It seems for werewolves, marriage is reduced to a roleplaying aspect. It comes down to choices, really.

The real question is, who would ever love a furry? :)

Comment: ...another furry? http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Aela_the_Huntress

Answer (score 0):

When you are a werewolf you can get married and gain money once a day. Some posts on the various wikis are not exactly truthful because I have found that you can get lover's comfort but you'll have a tough time, as you have a 1/100 chance of getting it.

People say that you cannot get it but I slept with my wife 100 times and I got lover's comfort only the once. I just had to do it again to be sure and yes I was right... you have a 1/100 chance of getting it.

Comment: Im pretty sure I got it every time. ( There is a minimum time you have to rest I Think - 8 hours or something )

Comment: "...you have a 1/100 chance of getting [lover's comfort]" This doesn't seem to be true as per: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lover's_Comfort#Lover.27s_Comfort